# In CakePHP 3.x how I can change the method of set and get

Tags: cakephp, entity, getter-setter

I use CakePHP 3.x.

I want to change the data before saving in database and getting it as I wish (like Encrypt & Decrypt).

I change the Set and Get function to simplifying (I wrote this code in Model\Entity\Student.php):

```
protected function _setFirst_name($value) {
    return "SET";
}

protected function _getFirst_name($value) {
    return "GET";
}
```

I want to save **Set** in Database but retrieve **Get**.

But in DataBase it saved just **Get**

Comment: Stuff like en/decryption should better be handled in a custom database type (**http://stackoverflow.com/q/32260229/1392379**). Besides that, your setter doesn't make too much sense, as it doesn't set anything? You shouldn't over-simplify things, as that makes it hard to give you proper advice. Also by convention both methods should be camelBacked.

Comment: I could be completely misreading this question. But couldn't you use Cakephp's Model callbacks to manipulate date eg (beforeSave()) encrypt data. And use entity class to store code for getting decrypted data. https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#beforesave