# cakephp reuse the encryption/decryption code in more than one model

Tags: cakephp, encryption

I am new to cakephp. Currently I have encryption code in beforeSave() and decryption code in beforeFind() of a model file. I want to reuse the same encryption/decryption codes in another model file. Which is the best method to reuse the codes?

Comment: Use a behavior or a custom database type **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260229/encryption-decryption-of-form-fields-in-cakephp-3**

Comment: Make sure that you don't put the encryption password in code that might go into a repository anywhere. It should be only in a config file or something similar.